# Как получить из ответа Яндекс геокодера запрашиваемый адрес?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Я отправляю в геокодер несколько адресов для получения координат точек и потом отлавливаю его результаты в методе then примерно таким кодом:

```
var geocoder = new ymaps.geocode(
    'Абакан, ул.Некрасова, 23',
    { results: 1 }
);
geocoder.then(
    function( res ) {
        // обработка ответа
        coord = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
    }
);
```

Геокодер возвращает ответы асинхронно, а мне надо понять для какого адреса что я передал вернулись координаты. Я научился это делать когда данные возвращаются в формате json, а для способа описанного выше это возможно?

Answer (score 0):

> мне надо понять для какого адреса что я передал вернулись координаты

Храните адрес в замыкании.

```
const address = 'Абакан, ул.Некрасова, 23';
ymaps.geocode(address, {results: 1}).then(function (res) {
    console.log({
        address: address,
        coordinates: res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates()
    });
})
```

Comment: Простите, а разве ваш вариант сильно от моего отличается? Если я сделаю перебор 10 адресов через each() и вызову 10 раз ymaps.geocode(), то я так понимаю, что в вашей переменной address (что выводится в консоль) будет храниться очередное значение из цикла each(), а не то, для которого вернулись координаты. Так? Тогда ведь гарантии, что это значение совпадет с возвращенными координатами.

Comment: @Mario62RUS в моем варианте в консоль выведется адрес для которого был вызван геокодер и результат геокодирования (координаты). Вы вроде этого и хотели: "мне надо понять для какого адреса что я передал вернулись координаты".

Comment: Мне надо чтобы это в цикле работало, для получения данных по нескольких городам.

Comment: @Mario62RUS покажите полный код и что у вас не получается

Comment: Я думаю что если ваш код обернуть вот в такой цикл
`var arr = [ 'Абакан, ул.Некрасова, 23', 'Абакан, ул.Некрасова, 24', 'Абакан, ул.Некрасова, 25' ];
arr.forEach( function( address, i, arr ) {
 ymaps.geocode(address, {results: 1}).then(function (res) {
  console.log({
   address: address,
   coordinates: res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates()
  });
 })
});`
то выдаваемые в консоль адреса не всегда будут совпадать с возвращаемыми координатами.

Comment: Почему? Вы пробовали запускать этот код? В замыкании в `console.log` будет тот же `address` для которого вызывался `ymaps.geocode`.

Comment: Потому что возврат в метод then, насколько я понимаю, будет происходить асинхронно и какое из переданных в цикле значение вернется в конкретный раз - неизвестно.

Comment: @Mario62RUS всё известно. Почитайте о том что такое замыкания и как они работают. https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/useful/javascript/lets-learn-javascript-closures